# Filter rows of a 2d array by the rows in another 2d array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, filtering, associative-array, array-difference

I have two arrays, and I am using `array_diff_assoc()` to get the difference, but it always returns the `common set` row in the result

It should be returning the `new q sets` row.  What's wrong with my approach?

Sample data:

```
$array1 = [
    [12 => 'new q sets'],
    [11 => 'common set']
]

$array2 => [
    [11 => 'common set']
];
```

After calling `array_diff_assoc($array1, $array2)`, my output is:

```
[
    [11 => 'common set']
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Two values from key => value pairs are considered equal only if `(string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2` . In other words a strict check takes place so the string representations must be the same.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php

[The `(string)` value of any array is `"Array"`.](http://ideone.com/AxQEv) Thus, your call to `array_diff_assoc` is effectively comparing these two things:

```
Array ( [0] => "Array" [1] => "Array" ) 
Array ( [0] => "Array" )
```

Since the thing that is different between those two is the `[1]` key/value pair from the first array, you get that back (`[1] => Array( [11] => common set )`).

Comment: @Suneth Put the 2nd array in as the first variable in the array_diff_assoc() function.

Comment: @Suneth Don't use `array_diff_assoc()`. It's not designed for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

in array_diff_assoc(), keys are also compared. Since [0] is available in second array and [1] is not available in second array so thats why the result is Array ( [1] => Array ( [11] => common set ) ) .

Answer (score 0):

When running your script in a modern php environment, the Warnings should indicate that you are using the wrong tool for the job.

Bad Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/jIUcq))

```
$array1 = [[12 => 'new q sets'], [11 => 'common set']];
$array2 = [[11 => 'common set']];

var_export(array_diff_assoc($array1, $array2));
```

Bad Output:

```
Warning: Array to string conversion in /in/jIUcq on line 6

Warning: Array to string conversion in /in/jIUcq on line 6
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    11 => 'common set',
  ),
)
```

You don't actually want to compare the first level indexes anyhow because related/matching rows may have different first level indexes.

---

Instead, you should use `array_udiff()` to compare the associative rows (and ignore the first level keys).  Making a 3-way comparison -- as `array_udiff()` expects from the callback -- without iterated function calls is possible with the "spaceship operator".  In the below snippet, `$a` and `$b` represent rows of data.

Proper Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/DSW9M))

```
var_export(
    array_udiff($array1, $array2, fn($a, $b) => $a <=> $b)
);
```

Proper Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    12 => 'new q sets',
  ),
)
```