# "Array to string conversion error" when calling array_diff_assoc() with a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-difference

I get array to string conversion error for the following line:

```
$diff = array_diff_assoc($stockist, $arr);
```

Here, `$arr` is an array decoded from a JSON file. Using the `is_array()` function I was able to verify that both parameters are arrays. Can someone point me the problem

```
$stockist = array();
while (!feof($file_handle)) {

    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM reorderchart WHERE medicine = '"
        . trim($line_of_text[3])
        . "' ORDER BY medicine";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if (trim($line_of_text[2]) - trim($line_of_text[1]) <= 0) {
        
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            $file = "results.json";
            $arr = json_decode(file_get_contents($file),true);
            $pharmacy = trim($row['Medicine']);

            if (isset($stockist[$pharmacy])) {
                    
                $medicine = $stockist[$pharmacy];
                $medicine[] = trim($row['Stockist']);
                $stockist[$pharmacy] = $medicine;

            } else {

                $medicine = array();
                $medicine[] = trim($row['Stockist']);
                $stockist[$pharmacy] = $medicine;
            }
        }
    }
}
$diff = array();
$diff = array_diff_assoc($stockist,$arr);
ksort($diff);
foreach ($diff as $key => $value) {

    echo "<table align='center' border='1'>";
    echo "<tr><td align = 'center'> <font color = 'blue'> $key</td></tr>";
    
    foreach($value as $key1 => $value1) {

        echo "<tr><td align ='center'>$value1</td></tr><br>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: Possible reason: multidimensional arrays

Comment: _"both parameters are arrays"_ Sure they are, and php says nothing different. The issue is an _array to string conversion_, not the other way around. The question is what do these arrays _contain_.

Comment: @viakondratiuk  Yes it is mutidimensional. But doesn't array_diff() evaluate only the first level

Comment: @user2963765 This function only checks one dimension of a n-dimensional array. Of course you can check deeper dimensions by using `array_diff($array1[0], $array2[0]);`.

Comment: You can use a `recursive array_diff`. check out this https://gist.github.com/jondlm/7709e54f84a3f1e1b67b, it solved my problem...

Comment: Unfortunately, this question isn't super clear because it does not reveal sample data for the two arrays being compared (as part of a [mcve]).

Answer (score 55):

According to it:

```
php -r 'array_diff(array("a" => array("b" => 4)), array(1));'
PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in Command line code on line 1
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() Command line code:0
PHP   2. array_diff() Command line code:1
```

One of your arrays is multidimensional.

`array_diff` only checks one dimension of a n-dimensional array. Of course you can check deeper dimensions by using `array_diff($array1[0], $array2[0]);`

Comment: Seems like a bug to me. "Array to string conversion" message is misleading at best.

Answer (score 30):

Yes, the strict answer is because "One of your arrays is multidimensional."

Another useful note might be - *depending on your needs of further parsing the actual differences* - consider first testing your arrays with:

```
$diff = strcmp(json_encode($stockist), json_encode($arr));
```

or

```
$diff = strspn(json_encode($stockist) ^ json_encode($arr), "\0");
```

or

```
$diff = xdiff_string_diff(json_encode($stockist), json_encode($arr));
```

All these options will compare the entire array tree, not just the top level.

Comment: $diff = strcmp(json_encode($stockist), json_encode($arr)); didn't work, always returns 0 when there's a diff between the two

Answer (score 30):

Since `array_diff` can only deals with one dimension, you can either:

- convert your multi-dimentional array into one dimension, e.g. by:

  - [flattening a multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1319903/55075), e.g.:

    ```
    while ($arr) {
      list($key, $value) = each($arr); 
      is_array($value) ? $arr = $value : $out[$key] = $value;
      unset($arr[$key]);
    }
    // Now $out is flatten version of $arr.
    ```
  - [serializing the array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23867870/55075), e.g.:

    ```
    $results = array_diff(array_map('serialize',$a2), array_map('serialize',$a1));
    ```
- use custom [recursive `array_diff`-like function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3876435/55075),

Comment: The flattening of a multidimensional array is wrong. When first nested array is approached the function is forgetting all other values in oruginal $arr.

Comment: Perfect! Unserialize worked as opposed to the most upvoted answer. Just needed to do $results = array_map('unserialize', $results); afterwords to read it

Comment: The second example was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!!

Answer (score 9):

You can see in the [array_diff() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) that:

> Two elements are considered equal if and only if (string) $elem1 ===
>   (string) $elem2. In other words: when the string representation is the
>   same.

So it looks like you can't use this function with multi dimensional array, or in fact any value that cannot be converted to a string. This is because the function will cast values to a `string` to do the comparison.

You can write your own function to recursively check arrays for a difference - in fact the following is from the comments of the docs linked above.

You can see the [comment here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php#91756).

```
function arrayRecursiveDiff($aArray1, $aArray2) { 
    $aReturn = array(); 

    foreach ($aArray1 as $mKey => $mValue) { 
        if (array_key_exists($mKey, $aArray2)) { 
            if (is_array($mValue)) { 
                $aRecursiveDiff = arrayRecursiveDiff($mValue, $aArray2[$mKey]); 
                if (count($aRecursiveDiff)) { $aReturn[$mKey] = $aRecursiveDiff; } 
            } else { 
                if ($mValue != $aArray2[$mKey]) { 
                    $aReturn[$mKey] = $mValue; 
                } 
            } 
        } else { 
            $aReturn[$mKey] = $mValue; 
        } 
    } 

    return $aReturn; 
}
```

Comment: it's astounding that PHP language writers thought it's fine to not write a recursive version of the function.
And to leave the array to string conversion error instead of making the error say something like "does not support multidimensional arrays"

Answer (score 8):

According to PHP documentation for the function

> Note:
>   Two elements are considered equal if and only if (string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2. In  words: when the string representation is the same.

For more information refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: I only need to compare keys. So I used array_diff_key(). But it is returning a null array.

Comment: If it's returning an empty array, it means that both arrays have the same set of keys.

Comment: I had a bug where I had two arrays considered different, but they clearly looked the same. This answer helped me compare their string representation, and it was indeed different.

Answer (score 3):

Came across this one while working on a platform upgrade for PHP 7.3 from 5.3 today... Since I'm storing this value for use later on, I wanted to be sure I didn't wind up with a 'partially' serialized array that may break things downstream.

Thanks kenorb for getting me onto the right path (I upvoted ur answer). The following is working nicely for me.

Code:

```
$a1 = [
  'foo' => 'bar',
  'bar' => [
    'test' => 'test'
  ],
  'foobar' => 'fizzbuzz'
];

$a2 = [
  'foobar' => 'fizzbuzz',
  'herp' => [
    'derp' => 'herpderp'
  ]
];

$diff = array_diff(array_map('serialize', $a1), array_map('serialize', $a2));

$multidimensional_diff = array_map('unserialize', $diff);

print_r($multidimensional_diff);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => bar
    [bar] => Array
        (
            [test] => test
        )

)
```

Comment: How is it different from the answer provided by kenorb?

Comment: it includes using `array_map('unserialize', $diff)` so that the format of the $diff array remains multidimensional w/o any serialization. I see it in the comments, but that text is tiny and easily overlooked.

Comment: Expanding on your answer slightly:
function diffMultiDim($dataLeft, $dataRight) {
    return array_map('unserialize', array_diff(array_map('serialize', $dataLeft), array_map('serialize', $dataRight)));
}

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution for a similar problem. I want to compare two associative arrays and return the changed values, but some of the elements are arrays. So if I use

```
array_diff_assoc
```

, it gives me "Array to string error". My function will also compare the elements which are arrays and if there's a difference, it will return the array element. It is still a work in progress and not tested extensively.
For example:

```
public static $example1 = [
    'id' => 1,
    'status' => 2,
    'elements' => ['test', 'example'],
    'different' => ['old' => 5, 'new' => 9]
];

public static $example2 = [
    'id' => 1,
    'status' => 3,
    'elements' => ['test', 'example'],
    'different' => ['old' => 5, 'new' => 8]
];

public static function test(){
    die(var_dump(self::udiffAssoc(self::$example1, self::$example2)));
}

public static function udiffAssoc(array $array1, array $array2)
{
    $checkDiff = function ($a, $b) use (&$checkDiff) {
        if (is_array($a) && is_array($b)) {
            return array_udiff_assoc($a, $b, $checkDiff);
        } elseif (is_array($a)) {
            return 1;
        } elseif (is_array($b)) {
            return -1;
        } elseif ($a === $b) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return $a > $b ? 1 : -1;
        }
    };
    return array_udiff_assoc($array1, $array2, $checkDiff);
}
```

if you run ::test it will return:

```
array(2) {
    ["status"]=>
    int(2)
    ["different"]=>
    array(2) {
    ["old"]=>
    int(5)
    ["new"]=>
    int(9)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same error and found the following bug report for php:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60198

> Some of the array_* functions that compare elements in multiple arrays
>   do so by  (string)$elem1 === (string)$elem2.
>
> If $elem1 or $elem2 is an array, then the array to string notice is
>   thrown.
>
> Two examples of functions that can throw this are array_intersect()
>   and  array_diff().
>
> If these functions are not expected to take arrays with other arrays
>   as values,  this should be mentioned on the documentation pages.

That report describes, why php throws an error on comparing a multi-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

What about my solution:

```
$diff = strcmp(serialize($arr1), serialize($arr2))
```

Comment: you're solution only returns the difference but i need the hole levels to return and the key of the differences

Answer (score 0):

We're getting cast to string warning because array_diff converts the elements to string before comparing... and we've passed ints, the key is to add a wrapper object since objects can be casted to string, then when comparison is done we're returning them back to ints as below

Or-

Your can just use a library https://github.com/voku/Arrayy#diffarray-array-static
its have method called **diff()** can compare straight integer and other data types as well

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who hits this, [array_udiff()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php) is a drop-in replacement that avoids the warning by using a callback instead of the internal string conversion. For example to diff `[['a' => 1, 'b' => 0]]` and `[['a' => 1, 'b' => 1]]`:

```php
array_udiff([['a' => 1, 'b' => 0]], [['a' => 1, 'b' => 1]], function ($a, $b) { return $a != $b; });
// [["a" => 1,"b" => 0]]
```

Or with an [arrow function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php) if using php 7.4+:

```php
array_udiff([['a' => 1, 'b' => 0]], [['a' => 1, 'b' => 1]], fn ($a, $b) => $a != $b);
// [["a" => 1,"b" => 0]]
```

Note that associative array comparison ignores key order, so `['a' => 1, 'b' => 0] == ['b' => 0, 'a' => 1]`

Comment: This is not demonstrating best practice.  [`callback(mixed $a, mixed $b): int` means that an integer should be returned](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php) Earlier posted answers of the technique: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73914366/2943403) , [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71199628/2943403) , [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73575650/2943403) , [4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71235629/2943403) , [5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71195049/2943403) , [6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70817582/2943403) , [7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51257853/2943403)