# filter unique array std object data from 2 php arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I have 2 array of std objects where i need to filter out array -> stdClass Object -> matching [code] and get final array with unique array -> stdClass Object -> [code]
here are examples array #1

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [code] => 100
            [c_price] => 438
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [code] => 1100
            [c_price] => 105
        )

)
```

here are examples array #2

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [code] => 100
            [c_price] => 1250
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [code] => 1100
            [c_price] => 300
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [code] => 4807
            [c_price] => 1000
        )

)
```

> Expected results i want to get

```
Array
(

    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [code] => 4807
            [c_price] => 1000
        )

)
```

i have tried many answers but not found any closer to my problem, i have tried array_unique but it's not working because of std object class, thanks in advance

Comment: Explain what you are trying to do. What is the relationship between array #1 and array #2? Why is that the expected result? Any code? Are you simply looking for [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [difference between two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077840/difference-between-two-arrays) - oh, realize the stdObject aspect might throw you off. Still stuck? Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495068/convert-stdclass-object-to-array-in-php for a quick fix. Otherwise iterate on collection.

Comment: What about array_diff_assoc()?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19495142/18078362  remove stdclass and then try array_unique

Comment: @KiranRaiChamling please show me example of array_diff_assoc() i need to use it in codeignitor i need to filter duplicates and return only unique just as example

Comment: @pk_ i cannot remove std object i need output 100% same as Expected

Comment: what is the use of stdclass???

Comment: @pk_ this is requirement there's lot of code i show you short example if you can please answer the question properly within criteria

Comment: you first ask the question properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242347/discussion-between-uzthegeek-and-pk).

Comment: This question is comparing two-dimensional data.  This means that [difference between two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10077840/2943403) is incorrect advice.  Please specifically see my advice at https://stackoverflow.com/a/71049380/2943403  You will need to isolate `$a->code` and `$b->code`.

Answer (score -2):

solved with

```
$arrdiff = array_diff_assoc($array2, $array1);
```

**cheers @ Kiran Rai Chamling**

Comment: This only works by happenstance.  This is not a reliable solution.

Comment: You can read about the folly of this answer here: [While comparing associative rows between two 2d arrays, array_diff_assoc() gives the wrong difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9885366/2943403)